# Angular 2 children routes cannot be matched

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I can't handle Angular 2 routing to manage following routes:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {MainMenuComponent} from "./main/main.component";
import {AdvancedMenuComponent} from "./advanced/advanced.component";
import {ImportMenuComponent} from "./import/import.component";
import {ImportTAComponent} from "./import/team-assignments/import-ta.component";
import {MenuComponent} from "./menu.component";

const menuRoutes:Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/menu/main',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'menu',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: MenuComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'main',
                component: MainMenuComponent,
                outlet: 'content'
            },
            {
                path: 'advanced',
                component: AdvancedMenuComponent,
                outlet: 'content'
            },
            {
                path: 'import',
                component: ImportMenuComponent,
                outlet: 'content'
            },
            {
                path: 'import/ta',
                component: ImportTAComponent,
                outlet: 'content'
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(menuRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class MenuRoutingModule {
}
```

While I'm trying to access /menu/main i get following error in console "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'menu/main'". Could someone help me with this? What's wrong with my routes? And how can I achieve required behaviour?

In a parent I have following html: 
`<router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>`

BTW, my parent is included as router-outlet too in a global module:

```
<router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

{
    path: '',
    component: NavbarComponent,
    outlet: 'navbar'
},
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/menu/menu.module#MenuModule'
}
```

Comment: If you have an route with an empty path `''` without child routes, use `pathMatch: 'full'` like `path: '',
                component: MenuComponent, pathMatch: 'full'`, otherwise Angular will look for child routes of this route instead of checking the siblings.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for your explanation. Just tried to do it, but didn't help. Still getting the same error

Comment: Don't use `outlet: ...` if you only have a single `<router-outlet>`. AFAIK there still must always be exactly one outlet without `name`. Otherwise a Plunker would be helpful. I wasn't successful with router-outlets with `name` at all so  far, but it's quite some time ago I tried the last time.